# How to make radiobutton click event add item to dictionary

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have a form with several radio buttons that gets created during run-time. The number of radio buttons will change depending on number of records in the db.
I can get the value from click event but, cannot add another item to dictionary. The code below, shows only information from current click event and does not add another item for second, third, and so on...click events.

```
Public Sub RadClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim rb As RadioButton
    Dim myDictionary As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
    Dim x As Integer = 0

    rb = DirectCast(sender, RadioButton)
    If rb.Checked = True Then
        x = x + 1
        myDictionary.Add(x, rb.Name)
    End If

    For Each pair As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String) In myDictionary
        MsgBox(pair.Key & " - " & pair.Value)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: My question ...is there a way to loop through radio buttons on the form and each time an event is fired, add an item to the dictionary. I want to be able to use this list of (1, rb.name), (2, rb.name)...etc , so that I can pass along to SQL insert statement.

Comment: This is a WinForm or an ASP.NET app? Do you want an entry in the Dictionary for each radiobutton checked? and if the radiobutton becomes unchecked do you want it removed from the dictionary? And finally, why do you need a dictionary? If you are interested on the checked radiobuttons a simple list should be enough.

Comment: It is a win form. Tried array....then an arraylist..... arraylist only held the one button click value and i could not add the next click. Basically arraylist was always length of one. I need a list of clicks added to arraylist so i can send them to a sql server table.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply.
I ended up getting this to work based on your suggestion to use a list.

```
Public Sub ComboClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim a_cb As ComboBox
    a_cb = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
    Dim x = a_cb.Name
    Dim h As Integer = 0
    'Dim pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)
    btnAll.Enabled = False
    ListID.Clear()
    Try
        Select Case a_cb.SelectedItem
            Case Is = "P"
                myDictionary.Add(x, a_cb.SelectedItem)
                a_cb.Enabled = False
            Case Is = "A"
                myDictionary.Add(x, a_cb.SelectedItem)
                a_cb.Enabled = False
            Case Is = "L"
                myDictionary.Add(x, a_cb.SelectedItem)
                a_cb.Enabled = False
        End Select
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    For Each pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In myDictionary
        If pair.Value = "P" Then ListID.Add(pair.Value)
        If pair.Value = "A" Then ListID.Add(pair.Value)
        If pair.Value = "L" Then ListID.Add(pair.Value)
        'MsgBox(pair.Key & " - " & pair.Value)
    Next
    If ListID.Count = ClRowCount Then
        btnAttend.Enabled = True
    Else
        btnAttend.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```